# Using tailwind purge option to remove unused css, but all styles are getting removed

Tags: tailwind-css, css-purge

Using tailwind purge option to remove unused css, but all styles are getting removed.

Reference: https://v2.tailwindcss.com/docs/optimizing-for-production#basic-usage

My tailwind.config.js file looks like below

```
module.exports = {
  purge: ['./src/page/**/*.js', './src/layouts/**/*.js', './components/**/*.js'],
  darkMode: false,
  theme: {}
}
```

Comment: why all three options in purge are same? If they all are same , write it once .

Comment: The above purge config worked fine, earlier i was giving wrong path for pages like './src/page/**/*.js'.

Now working fine with 
 purge: ['./src/pages/**/*.js', './src/layouts/**/*.js', './components/**/*.js'],

Comment: @user12417761 I have given wrong path earlier , now correct path it worked fine.